# Acceder a un archivo en red con html con http o file?

Tags: html, servidor, redes

Esa es mi duda, tengo dos pcs conectados por red, cada uno tiene unos html, uno tendría solo el de fuera de servicio para cuando se cae la red, y el otro el resto, entonces tengo que acceder por red al resto. El caso que si uso "file://" con la IP de acceso a la carpeta chrome me da el siguiente error :  "Cross origin requests are only suported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, https"
Sin embargo si uso http no responde ni accede al archivo, la dirección IP de acceso a las carpetas está bien, ya que por explorador de archivos si que accedo, pero al intentar acceder por html no. Necesitaría un servidor apache o algún tipo de permisos? Tengo mis dudas por eso, porque están conectados en red y mediante explorador de archivos yendo a IP://carpeta/www/htmls funciona ... Muchas gracias !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error con `file://` en el navegador es evidente. No puedes acceder al sistema de archivos de otra máquina mediante el navegador.

Para acceder a un archivo html desde el navegador, alojado en otra máquina accesible mediante TCP/IP, es posible gracias al protocolo `HTTP`, este protocolo es el que incorporan los servidores web. La máquina `host`debe disponer de un servidor web (Apache, IIS, etc.) configurado para que muestre estos archivos. El servidor web será visible en la red, mediante el navegador, por su IP, o el DNS (nombre de dominio) asignado. Habitualmente por el puerto por defecto (80).

Comment: Desconocía eso, pensaba que podía prescindir del servidor al estar conectados en red, como si al ser la misma red se pudiesen considerar locales ambos, he probado con apache y http y todo genial, muchísimas gracias!